# Induction on a sequence inequality

Tags: induction

Let a sequence $X_0, X_1, X_2, . . .$ be defined in the following way:
\begin{equation*}
X_0 = 1
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
X_1 = 2
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
X_n = 3X_{n−1} + 2X_{n−2}.
\end{equation*}

Prove that $\forall n \geq 0 : X_n \leq 4^n$. What are the base cases? What is the inductive step?

I made it as far as getting the following inequality in my inductive step but I can't proceed any further.

\begin{equation*}
11X_{n-1}+2X_{n-2}\leq4^{n+1}
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

with inductive assumption, you have
$$
\begin{split}
X_n &= 3X_{n-1} + 2X_{n-2} \\
    &\le 3\cdot 4^{n-1} + 2 \cdot 4^{n-2} \\
    &= 3\cdot 4^{n-1} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot 4^{n-1} \\
    &= 4^n - 0.5\cdot 4^{n-1}
\end{split}
$$
Can you finish this?

Comment: Why would you add $1$? $X_n\le 4^n$ not $4^n+1$

Comment: @Andrei in the initial version of the question OP wanted to prove $X_n \le 4^n+1$

Comment: I did not notice that. Sorry.